# Pixel-alignment and anti-aliasing in a TextView

Tags: android

I'm having trouble getting consistent font rendering in a text view, it looks like the anti-aliasing is causing the problem but the end result is that the widths of different characters vary a fair amount. Here's a zoomed in look at the problem, this is from a single TextView using Roboto-thin. Compare the "I" from the first line with the "L" in the second line:

[image: zoom in on text rendering]

This screenshot is uses a 36sp font on a 720 pixel wide xhdpi phone. The effect is worse on smaller font sizes (as anti-aliasing becomes more important). Is there anything I can do to affect the placement of characters at the pixel level that might improve things?

Comment: I'm pretty sure antialiasing artifacts are working as intended because letterforms in fonts have different offsets (I.e. the stems of the I and L are at different horizontal offsets in the font). Not sure what you're referring to though about different character widths?

Comment: Thanks for looking into it, after doing a bunch more reading, I think what I'm looking for is something like the Sharp text rendering style in Photoshop, coupled with a way to reduce fractional widths: http://cogniance.com/design-team/creating-pixel-perfect-text-small-size-adobe-photoshop#.U-5XEoBdVPQ I'm also now realizing that's unrealistic in a mobile text rendering setting. Since the effect is more pronounced on the thin font, I've switched to roboto light and it's much better. I think that might be my only option for now.